# How to access jquery object in ajax call success - Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, dom, syntax-error

I am trying to access the elements within the xml response object, but I'm getting Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Here's the xml:

```
<ASIInventory request="01/28/2013 08:01" excute="366">
<Inventory SKU="102040">
<ItemId>920-002478</ItemId>
<Description>
<![CDATA[
Logitech Keyboard 920-002478 Desktop K120 USB Black Retail
]]>
</Description>
<Vendor>Logitech</Vendor>
<Category>KB</Category>
<SubCategory>98</SubCategory>
<UPC>097855065537</UPC>
<Price>11.00</Price>
<Rebate>
<![CDATA[ none ]]>
</Rebate>
<Term>none</Term>
<Weight>1.63</Weight>
<Status>ACTIVE</Status>
<Qty>
<Branch Code="1016" Name="Fremont">44</Branch>
<Branch Code="1028" Name="Los Angeles">121</Branch>
<Branch Code="1116" Name="Atlanta">47</Branch>
<Branch Code="1216" Name="Chicago">37</Branch>
<Branch Code="1316" Name="Dallas">23</Branch>
<Branch Code="1516" Name="Kansas">0</Branch>
<Branch Code="1716" Name="New Jersey">3</Branch>
<Branch Code="2416" Name="Miami">0</Branch>
<Branch Code="2616" Name="Portland">0</Branch>
</Qty>
</Inventory>
</ASIInventory>
```

Here is my browser script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'some.xml', 
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
     var test = $(xml).find('Vendor').text();
     alert(test);
   }
  }); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it me, or you have an extra '}); ' at the end of your script? Other than that it seems ok to me, or at which line does the console says you got an error?